# How to delete specific multiple columns that have zeroes?

Tags: excel, vba

Are there any ways to automatically delete zeroes in specific columns(not manually click and delete) which in this case columns that have voltage as header? Because my existing codes(not referring to the codes below) somehow often generate unwanted zeroes in row 7 and 8 and I want to get rid of them to reduce confusion. My codes doesn't cause any error but it just couldn't get rid of the zeroes at that highlighted rows.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub deletingstuff()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastColumn
With sht
If sht.Cells(1, i).Value = "Voltage" & sht.Cells(lastrow + 1, i).Value = 0 Then
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.ClearContents
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.ClearContents
End If
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a question but: *"Because my existing codes(not referring to the codes below) **somehow often** generate unwanted zeroes in row 7 and 8 and I want to get rid of them to reduce confusion."* Wouldn't you rather try tackle this issue instead? =)

Comment: Should we understand that you only want to clear the zero value in the rows 7 and 8 for columns heaving their header = `Voltage`?

Comment: @JvdV ok previously the unwanted zeroes arises when I tried to make negatives values in specific columns labels as voltage to absolute, it will cause the blank cells to generate zero value. I don't really know how to solve this issue so I was thinking to use Vba to get rid of the zeroes.

Comment: @FaneDuru yup!!

Comment: As @JvdV said, it would be a better practice to deal with the source of the actual issue. Other than that, avoid using `ActiveCell` and `.Selection`. Always refer to cells explicitly. The cells you need to clear are `sht.Cells(lastrow + 1, i)` and `sht.Cells(lastrow + 2, i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, please:

```
Sub deletingstuff()

Dim i As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
'Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastColumn
    With sht
        If sht.Cells(1, i).Value = "Voltage" Then
            If sht.Cells(7, i) = 0 Then sht.Cells(7, i).Clear
            If sht.Cells(8, i) = 0 Then sht.Cells(8, i).Clear
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```